# Use NG-CLICK to change class on a clicked element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I am creating dynamic tabs using ajax data loaded via the WordPress REST-API. Everything is working, but I need to add a class to the active tab in order to use CSS transforms on it.

I would appreciate any suggestions. I know how to use ng-class when clicking one element affects another, but not when it affects the clicked element. It's also worth noting I am using the 'as' syntax for the ng-controller.

```js
JAVASCRIPT:

  var homeApp = angular.module('homeCharacters', ['ngSanitize']);
homeApp.controller('characters', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.myData = {
    tab: 0
  }; //set default tab
  $http.get("http://bigbluecomics.dev/wp-json/posts?type=character").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData.data = response.data;
  });
});
homeApp.filter('toTrusted', ['$sce',
  function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
HTML:

<div class="more_comics_mobile"><a href="javascript:void(0)">More Comics <img src="./images/white-arrow.png" /></a>
</div>
<section class="characters" ng-app="homeCharacters" ng-controller="characters as myData">
  <div class="char_copy" ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-bind-html="item.content | toTrusted" ng-show="myData.tab === item.menu_order">
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
  <div class="char_tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul ng-init="myData.tab = 0" ng-model='clicked'>
        <li class="tab" ng-repeat="item in myData.data">
          <a href ng-click="myData.tab = item.menu_order">
            <img src="{{ item.featured_image.source }}" />
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to add the class to the li element. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` like

```
<li class="tab" ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-class="{'active' : item.menu_order == myData.tab}"></li>
```

For more options you can visit
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="more_comics_mobile"><a href="javascript:void(0)">More Comics <img src="./images/white-arrow.png" /></a>
</div>
<section class="characters" ng-app="homeCharacters" ng-controller="characters as myData">
  <div class="char_copy" ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-bind-html="item.content | toTrusted" ng-show="myData.tab === item.menu_order">
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
  <div class="char_tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul ng-init="myData.tab = 0" ng-model='clicked'>
        <li class="tab" ng-click="activate($index)" ng-repeat="item in myData.data">
          <a href ng-click="myData.tab = item.menu_order">
            <img src="{{ item.featured_image.source }}" />
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

in your js

```
$scope.activate = function(index){
       document.getElementsByClassName.setAttribute("class","tab");

       document.getElementsByClassName[index].setAttribute("class","tab active");
}
```

Comment: hmmmm this does not seem to have an effect. (it did not add a class to the active tab)